# Can I edit Stripe invoice description by adding human-readable time

Tags: stripe-payments, invoice

I would like to know if I can make invoice in Stripe like this

`Name           Spent time`
`Project 1.        02:33            $4.55`

I'm interesting how to add time in this format into invoice. Can i add formula there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the sample, it looks like you're referring to customisation of line items in an invoice. Such customisation is not possible.

You can refer to this doc about what can be customised for the invoice: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/customize